# JavaFX TableView sections

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, tableview, grouping

On JavaFX, I want to create a `TableView` with sections on it, like the Address Book of Android or iOS, in which you have a section for every letter of the alphabet.

I've tried using `TableRow` with `setGraphic()` or `setText()`, but as they get reused, every row ends up being a section after I scroll a bit, even after trying to reset the graphic/text to `null`.

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi! No, sorry. In the end I think I changed toolkits. JavaFX is too buggy at this state for my purposes (not due to this but other bugs).

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to implement the sections is to use an overlay e.g. a VBox with Labels so in pseudo-code it looks like this:

```
AnchorPane p = new AnchorPane() {
   protected void layoutChildren() {
     super.layoutChildren();
     // position vbox
   }
};
TableView tv = new TableView();
AnchorPane.setLeft(tv,0);
AnchorPane.setTop(tv,0);
AnchorPane.setBottom(tv,0);
AnchorPane.setRight(tv,0);
p.getChildren().add(tv);
VBox b = new VBox();
for( int i = 0; i < 26; i++ ) {
  b.getChildren().add(new Label(...));
  // register listners and scroll list
}
p.getChildren().add(b);
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work correctly as those labels will hide some rows unless I'm missing something, besides being very cumbersome, having to keep track of scrolling and all...

Comment: I thought you are talking about the fast scrolls (A,B,C,...) on the right - anyways also the sections are partially overlays at least on my iphone.

So for sections you need both:
* make section rows display differently
* add one overlay control which shows the current section string